# Accurate Triggering of Commands to Music

Tags: synchronization, raspberry-pi, timing

I'm creating a light show to be synchronized to music, looking to control with a Raspberry PI. Mains Voltage, dimming, so relays are out of the question. I'll use servos to control physical dimmers, controlled by the ServoBlaster package over GPIO. I've got that pretty well under way.

My question is in regard to timing. I need to execute a large series of commands very accurately over about ten minutes (the commands to the servos that will trigger the lights in sync with the music).

Can you recommend a way to do this?

Thanks,

Keith

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like that you want to play your music and control your light show independently. And your sync mechanism is the clock. I guess it would be much better if the music would trigger your lightshow.

Anyway, what you probably already tried is to run the commands and look how long they take. But as Linux is not a real time OS, you heavily depend on the load of your system (I have tested that already for my project [Raspberry Pi GPIO Web Control](https://bitbucket.org/sbub/raspberry-pi-gpio-web-control) -  For me it took about 2-5ms on an idle Raspberry Pi to set all 17 ports; with some artificial load (e.g.'find /' in the background) it was 10-15ms slower. If you multiply this up to 10 Minutes, it is not exact at all.

If you want to try it anyway, I would recommend you split your large series of commands in smaller packages and call these packages (scripts) triggered by absolute time (don't use "sleep" as it is relative), but I guess that your result won't satisfy you. As I said: look for a way to trigger your lightshow by the music (maybe use some GPIO-ports with an Analog-Digital-Converter with a microphone connected).

Comment: I like this. I wonder if could set something up like:

hit go at "x" time
package one is triggered at "x"+0
package two is triggered at "x"+5 sec
package three is triggered at "x"+10 sec

Triggers would be set up to align major beats.

I considered triggering the lightshow by the music, but I don't want to see the lights simply react to the music, I want fine control that is in sync with the music. I think the triggered packages could do that well.

Do you think I need to look into an outside absolute time source, or will there be an accurate absolute time source onboard the Pi?

Thanks!